# Kotlin BuildConfig Deprecated in SDK 34 (target API 13), what is new method

Tags: android, kotlin

android.BuildConfig.DEBUG and BuildConfig are no longer available. I even added in

```
build.gradle compileOptions {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-opt-in=kotlin.reflect.optIn"
    }
}
```

did not help.

At runtime in the application class I want to check if BuildConfig.DEBUG for logging and other actions, but not for production.  What is the new, correct way to do this. I could test the version name, but this is a hack.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google, with 100% Kotlin apps, this is the solution:  Add the following to the app build.gradle

```
android {
namespace = "..."
compileSdk = nn
android.buildFeatures.buildConfig = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `build.gradle` to configure build variants with separate flags for debug and release:

Update gradle file:-

```
  buildTypes {
    debug {
        isDebuggable true
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_DEBUG', 'true'
    }
    release {
        isDebuggable false
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_DEBUG', 'false'
    }
}
```

Add a static member `IS_DEBUG` to your application class.

```
object App {
    val IS_DEBUG = BuildConfig.IS_DEBUG
}
```

Then, throughout your code, you can simply use `App.IS_DEBUG` to check if the build is debug.

```
if (App.IS_DEBUG) {
    // Debug behavior, like enable logging
} else {
    // Production behavior, like disable logging
}
```

That's it. Happy coding..

Comment: This code does not compile as is using the latest SDK 34. Besides this, productFlavors is not the intention. If I modify buildTypes, that is Ok, but in the activity there is no BuildConfig class, it has been removed in SDK 34. That is is my challenge. I'm thinking it should be as simple as it used to be, in the application class I could check if the build was debug. How is this done now? Example of the old way:  if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(object : Timber.DebugTree() {

Comment: Updated my answer. Hopefully, Now works. If not then use:- 
if (System.getProperty("debug.mode") == "true") {
    // Debug behavior
} else {
    // Production behavior
}